# Need help decreasing width of table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to decrease the width of this table because it's way too wide.

[image]

I added this: `style="width: 70%;` to the table tag but it does not seem to work.

```
 <table align="center" class="data_table vert_scroll_table" style="width: 70%;">
```

```
     <ctl:vertScroll height="300" headerStyleClass="data_table_scroll"   bodyStyleClass="data_table_scroll" enabled="${user.scrollTables}">
   <ctl:sortableTblHdrSetup topTotal="false" href="process.like_item_search"/>
<table align="center" class="data_table vert_scroll_table" style="width: 70%;">
    <tr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="MWSLIN" property="mwslin" type="top">MWSLIN</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="SOR" property="sorCode" type="top">SOR</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="Fiscal Year" property="fiscalYear" type="top">Fiscal<br/>Year</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="Workload Year" property="workloadYear" type="top">Workload<br/>Year</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="SAC" property="sac" type="top">SAC</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="TAMCN" property="tamcn" type="top">TAMCN</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="NSN" property="nsn" type="top">NSN</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="WORKTYPE" property="workTypeId" type="top">Work Type</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="NOMENCLATURE" property="nom" type="top">Nomenclature</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <ctl:sortableTblHdr title="SUP" property="sup" type="top">Sup</ctl:sortableTblHdr>
        <th class="narrow">Actions</th>
   </tr>

    <c:forEach var="bean" items="${likeItems}">

        <tr>
            <td class="center">${bean.mwslin}</td>
            <td class="center">${bean.sorCode.shortName}</td>
            <td class="center">${bean.fiscalYear}</td>
            <td class="center">${bean.workloadYear}</td>
            <td class="center">${bean.sac}&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center">${bean.tamcn}&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center"><ctl:stringFormat format="@@@@-@@-@@@-@@@@">${bean.nsn}</ctl:stringFormat>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center">${bean.workTypeId.description}&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center">${bean.nom}&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="center"><fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${bean.sup}"/>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
            <a class="view" href="blah"><img class="edit" src="../images/icon_view.gif" border="0" alt="View"/></a>
            </td>


       </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
 </ctl:vertScroll>


</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:set var="no_results_msg" scope="page" value="There are no results that match your search criteria." />
  <%@ include file="../../include/search-no-results.html" %>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<%@ include file="../../include/footer.html" %>
```

Comment: Its Java...its not a java issue tho

Comment: Do you want a fluid width (automatically adjustable) or are you fine with a fixed-width table? For fixed width tables, using a pixel-value attribute to the table column widths should force the text to wrap (provided there's some spaces in the text)

Comment: Very nice JustChris...how do you do the "fluid width"?

Comment: Now that i think of it...it actually is adjusting automatically...I guess I just need a max-width so the scroll bars wont pop-up!!...thanx

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant HTML and CSS only?  Not everyone can read Java.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pixel value attribute in table columns should force the text to wrap (if there's at least one space in it). Use `style="width: 100px"` and set the amount to whatever you need. Alternatively, set this attribute to the column's class name in CSS if you're able to.

Comment: I just changed the class on the <td>'s just to make the font smaller...thanks any way :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you most likely have is that the `<td>`s, somewhere (in a CSS file, or in the document), have a fixed width. If that's the case, changing the `<table>` width won't do anything unless you have some other special styles on it.

For a responsive table width, I'd suggest adding a percentage-based width to both the `<table>` and the `<td>` elements. You would do this in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's just expanding to fit its contents.

As a fix, you might set a fixed width for columns such as  "Work Type" that could get too wide.